# Kivy: TypeError: NoneType object is not callable for MainApp().run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to make an app in Python + Kivy. Whenever I try to run it in PyCharm, it says that `DigitalLove().run()` has the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. The full log is below:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\paisseon\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-08-28_14.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.2.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-20c14b2, 20200615
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\paisseon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\paisseon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/paisseon/Downloads/DigitalLove/main.py", line 846, in <module>
     DigitalLove().run()
   File "C:\Users\paisseon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\paisseon\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm just starting to learn Kivy, so forgive me if it is a beginner's mistake but I could not find a solution by searching here or Google.

Thank you in advance :)

EDIT:
Minimal reproducible example

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

GUI = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class DigitalLove(App):
    @property
    def build(self):

        return GUI

        monika_art = 'images/monika.png'
        textbox_img = 'images/textbox.png'

        doki_response = 'example text'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DigitalLove().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<GUI>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: root.monika_art

            TextInput:
                id: user_input
                text: root.textinput_text
                multiline: False
                font_size: '12sp'
                # Add pos_hint and size_hint

            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                Image:
                    source: root.textbox_img
                    pos: self.parent.pos
                    size: self.parent.size
                # Add pos_hint and size_hint
                    Label:
                        text: root.doki_response
                        font_size: '16sp'
                        center: self.parent.center
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I added one in the edit. Thank you for letting me know I need to add it, I am new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems here:

- You should not use the `@property` decorator for the `build()` method
- You reference `GUI` in your `kv`, bu you have not defined a `GUI` class
- You reference several `root.` properties in your `kv` (which would refer to properties in a `GUI` class), but they are not defined.
- You have some code after the `return` in your `build()` method. Any code after a `return` will never be executed.
- In your `kv`, your indentation makes the `TexInput` and `GrdLayout` children of the `canvas`, but that won't work.
- Also in your `kv`, the top level rule is `<GUI>:` which create a rule to follow when creating a `GUI` class instance, but you have no code to create such an instance. You can fix that by changing `<GUI>:` to `GUI:` Or even better, change the class name to `Gui`.

Here is a modified version of your code with the above corrections:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Gui(BoxLayout):
    monika_art = StringProperty('images/monika.png')
    textbox_img = StringProperty('images/textbox.png')
    doki_response = StringProperty('example text')
    textinput_text = StringProperty('textinput text')

GUI = Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class DigitalLove(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DigitalLove().run()
```

main.kv:

```
Gui:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: root.monika_art

    TextInput:
        id: user_input
        text: root.textinput_text
        multiline: False
        font_size: '12sp'
        # Add pos_hint and size_hint

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Image:
            source: root.textbox_img
            pos: self.parent.pos
            size: self.parent.size
        # Add pos_hint and size_hint
            Label:
                text: root.doki_response
                font_size: '16sp'
                center: self.parent.center
```

A top level rule in `kv` without `<>` becomes a root widget (only one allowed in a `kv` file). When that `kv` file is loaded, the root widget is created (if there is a root widget defined) and returned.

Also, creating a variable (`GUI`) with the same name as a class (`GUI`), is a bad idea. It might work, but it is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: So if I wanted to, for example, change doki_response from "example text" to "new text" later on in main.py, would the proper way to do it be `Gui.doki_response = StringProperty('new text')`? And the same for changing textbox_img from "textbox.png" to "textbox_glitch.png" would be `Gui.textbox_img = StringProperty('images/textbox_glitch.png')`? Also if you don't mind, where would be a good place to learn Kivy besides looking at just documentation (which is for 1.11.1 not 2.0.0) and Erik Sandberg's YT videos? Thank you ^^

Comment: No, still using my answer code, you can change the text using `GUI.doki_response = 'Abba Dabba'`. Note that the difference is , in my answer, `GUI` is the instance of the `Gui` class. That changes the value of the `StringProperty`, and the binding set up by Kivy will set that new value in the `Label`. You can change any of those 4 `StringProperties` in the same way.

Comment: My experience is that the tutorials I have seen are good for learning the basics, but rarely  get much beyond the very basic straightforward situations. That makes sense as it would be impossible to create a tutorial that covered every situation. StackOverflow is a good place to search for answers. Once you have a good grasp of the basics, the best way to learn is to write code.